# How to set IDL, so users can tell a parameter is "optional" in VBA?

Tags: vba, default-value, idl, option-type

In an IDL, I define a method:

```
[id(1), helpstring("BLAH")] HRESULT SomeMethod([in, optional, defaultvalue(NULL)] IDispatch* para);
```

When I use this method in VBA, the screen tip only shows:

```
SomeMethod([para As Object])
```

What I want is that, there's some indication saying this parameter is "optional", or at least say there is a default parameter "NULL". Like this:

```
SomeMethod([[optional]para As Object])
```

or at least

```
SomeMethod([para As Object = NULL])
```

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In VBA, optional parameters are in brackets. i.e.

MsgBox(prompt[, buttons] [, title] [, helpfile, context])

buttons, title, helpfile and context are all optional arguments for the MsgBox Function.

The brackets are the indicator that a parameter is optional. **There is no other indicator**.

As a workaround, you could add "optional_" to the beginning of variables that you want to display as optional. ex:

```
Function DoSomething(Optional optional_Value As String) As String
```

Now you can see in the Intellisense the word "optional_" as part of the variable name.